# Looking for ''test management tool'' for manual testing

Tags: manual-testing, test-management

I am researching *Test Management tool* for creating test plan, test cases, test coverage, test matrix, reports and also should integrate with automation tools with providing some features for e.g. test modifications, duplication, test coverage etc.

Comment: What have you researched so far?

Answer (score 1):

Although this answer can be found rather very quickly using mighty Google search, but anyway for manual testing I would highly recommend TestLodge, it is very good tool and basic package should be sufficient for several small projects or two big.

It can be connected with various platforms, but as far as I know there is no connection with automated testing, but on the other I didn't search every option that was available over there :)

For more information about TestLodge: [click here](https://www.testlodge.com/tour).

Also check out [this list](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/15-best-test-management-tools-for-software-testers/), you can find something that suits your need.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/bug-tracking)

it is contain more features will help you

Answer (score 0):

The Best Tool in Manual Testing is HP Application Lifecycle Management (HP ALM). Moreover many [Software Testing Companies](https://www.qasource.com/software-testing-company) are using this successfully.

Comment: please define what is best for you, the price of HPs products makes them much less the desirable for me